# Choosing the right cassette

Tags: road-bike, cassette, trainer, wahoo

I have bought a Wahoo Kickr Core; I am seeking to get a cassette for my bike trainer.

I have a  Felt F95 [Bike Pic](https://ibb.co/d6kYkt0) road bike with the following part details:

- Rear Cassette - 8 cogs (The biggest cog has 23 teeth, smallest I think it was 11 teeth)
- Front Cassette - 3 cogs
- Gear Changers: Shimano Sora Flightdeck

Which cassette range is possible on a particular bike? and when would I need to buy a new chain?

Comment: Aside - consider getting a new one for your bike and put the old one on the trainer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest is to find the same cassette and to install it on the trainer (that you need to install with a 1.85mm spacer, normally in the box of the kickr): your derailleur is already tuned for this kind of cassette.

If you want to extend the range, then you indeed need a longer chain (so a new one), but most importantly, you need to make sure that the rear derailleur has enough capacity. If a short cage derailleur is fitted on the bike, it's possible that it won't handle larger cassettes (but to be more sure about that, it's necessary to have the exact reference of the derailleur).

Comment: I have the following Shimano Sora derailleur. I am not sure if this would support a 10 gear cassette  https://ibb.co/0VfgHkw

Comment: With a long cage, the number of gears will remain the same, what would change is the size of the cogs.

Comment: Staying with the original Sora derailleur probably means end of story at 27T, only the total capacity changes between SS and GS versions - see [link to Shimano docs](https://www.rennrad-news.de/forum/attachments/1587544848693-png.775099/).

Comment: Thanks for the addition, not knowledgeable on road groupsets. Note that increase range would be beneficial if you want to take full advantage of the trainer, as the kickr core can "simulate" up to 15% slopes, which would be very hard with the stock cassette (but you can also limit the max slope percentage).

Comment: hello @Renaud, DoNuT thank you for information.
If I stay with the current Shimano Sora RD-3300 3x8 speed what cassette with how many cogs and number of teeth would you suggest? I am looking for a new cassette and chain.

I would want to get the best of the 15% slope capability of the trainer

Comment: @ebe according to the specs, 11-27 8-speed. Note that if you change the derailleur as well (always in 8-speed, otherwise you'll have to change the shifter as well), you could potentially go higher 11-32 with a Acera RD-M3020 (it's technically a MTB derailleur, but in 8-speed, it doesn't matter).

Comment: @Renaud, I just checked Acera RD-M3020 and it is not even that expensive. 
I see that most of the 8 gears cassettes are 11-28. I assume that is still ok.
Moreover, what would happen if I get 10 gear cassette with a. 11-25 or b. 11-28. thank  you in advance!

Comment: @ebe I wrote 11-32 because you can find such cassette (CS-HG51-8 for example). If you go to a higher number of gears, there will be a mismatch between the amount of movement that the derailleur needs to move for changing speeds and its actual movement.